# Java Azure SDK, How to delete Secondary IP in network interface?

Tags: java, azure, networking, interface

I'm trying to delete secondary IP in the network interface, can't find how to do it using Azure java SDK.
Is it possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me what you have tried?

Comment: found how to do it in the Azure CLI command:

"az network nic ip-config delete --name subIpConfig200 --nic-name Auto4_Client_eth1 --resource-group Auto4_DP"

but as I wrote can't find it in the Azure SDK, tried something like that, But it's not working:

"azure.networkInterfaces().getByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName, interfaceName).ipConfigurations().remove("sub1");"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following cdoe

Create a service principal and assign Azure RABC role `Contributor` to the sp

Sdk

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
      <version>1.38.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code

```
 String clientId="232a1***";
        String clientSecret="?****";
        String tenant="e***";
        String subId="e*****";
        ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId,
                tenant,
                clientSecret,
                AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

        Azure azure= Azure.configure()
                .withLogLevel(LogLevel.BODY_AND_HEADERS)
                .authenticate(credentials)
                .withSubscription(subId);

        NetworkInterface nic = azure.networkInterfaces().getByResourceGroup("andywin7","testnic");

        nic.update().withoutIPConfiguration("ipconfig2")
                .apply();
```

Before Running code
[image]

After running code
[image]